# Why do these queries kill MySQL performance? How can I fix them?

Tags: mysql, performance, cpu

I created a slow query log to figure out what was causing my servers CPU usage to spike when the site was under load. I found these queries.

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_over = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 2545188  Schema: qe QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.162958  Lock_time: 0.000030  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 218089
```

Many of these are popping up because we have a lobby system which refreshes by running this query. This can easily be run 200+ times a minute and I feel like this is causing the insane CPU usage you may have seen in my other posts. (400%+  when under load, 8 cores). Here is an example of another one popping up in the log quite often.

```
SELECT * FROM deposits WHERE game_id = '109067' AND user_id = '19153';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 2545260  Schema: qe QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.261047  Lock_time: 0.000038  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined:   218091
```

I know there is a serious problem considering the rows examined/sent ratio, but I am stumped as of what to do about it. I already tweaked my.cnf according to the tuner over the course of a weeks time. The games table has about 120k rows and the deposits table has around 250k rows.

In the end I know my server will not scale, so how can I fix these queries and others to perform well under load?

Comment: first question is why are you trying to pull everything back? How many columns are you your table and can you provide some sample data

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before your queries and MySQL will give you a nice report on how it's planning to get the data out. I'd guess you need an index on game ID and user ID.

Comment: Both queries are fast but if they are called 200 times a minute you need some kind of cache.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know much without you showing us the schemata of `games` and `deposits`, but if you don't have an index on `game_over` in `games` (or even better, a compound index on `game_over` and `id DESC` in that order), and an index on `game_id` in `deposits` (or even better, a compound index on `game_id` and `user_id`), then that's the beginning of your problems.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Should I be using a "key" index for these tables? My id column is a "primary" index for both problematic tables. I don't understand what a compound index is?

Comment: EDIT: Adding keys to all fields referencing the userid brought down the CPU usage a TON! Thanks. It's still hovering around 100-200% though.

Comment: @SteveP: Sure.  Yes, a "key" index.  A compound index is an index that has more than one column in it; a query can only look at one index, so if your query is searching more than one column, it can only get full indexed performance if the index has all the columns it's searching.  Read here for more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: @SteveP - @chaos is saying `INDEX(game_id, user_id)`, not `INDEX(game_id)` plus `INDEX(user_id)`.  A compound (composite) index is better in your second case.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
Select * from.....
```

I would suggest using specific fields required from the table

:

```
Select id,name,......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes, but you also need to phrase your queries correctly.

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM games
WHERE game_over = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The optimal index is on `games(game_over, id desc)`.  This satisfies both the `where` clause and the `order by`.  That is fine.

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM deposits
WHERE game_id = '109067' AND user_id = '19153';
```

The optimal index is on `deposits(game_id, user_id)` (the columns can be in either order).  Note, however.  If the id fields are numeric, then drop the quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM deposits
WHERE game_id = 109067 AND user_id = 19153;
```

Using the wrong types in comparisons can result in the index not being used.  (I think your particular example is ok, but it is still a bad habit.)

Explicitly listing the columns is unlikely to improve performance.  However, it is a good idea because it makes the code more robust if tables change.